# Dynamic parameter accessing default value

Tags: powershell, optional-parameters, strict-mode

I have a PowerShell function that takes an optional parameter, validated using a `ValidateSetAttribute`, and based on that value it adds another dynamic parameter. However, **in strict mode**, when trying to access the parameter inside of the `DynamicParam` block, and I didn’t explicitely set said parameter, then I get an error that the variable was not defined.

```powershell
Param(
    [Parameter()]
    [ValidateSet('A', 'B')]
    [string] $Target = 'A'
)
DynamicParam {
    if ($Target -eq 'B') { # <- Here it fails
        # Add new parameter here...
    }
}
end {
    Write-Host $Target
}
```

The script works when called with `A` or `B` as the first parameter, but fails when the parameter is omitted. Interestingly, if I remove either the `ParameterAttribute` or the `ValidateSetAttribute` from the parameter definition it works.

My current workaround is to access the variable using `$PSBoundParameters` and check if the parameter was set, like this:

```
if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Target') -and $PSBoundParameters.Target -eq 'B') {
    # Add new parameter here...
}
```

While this works fine, it has one downside if I want to check for the value `A` instead: As `A` is the parameter’s *default value* it won’t be added to `$PSBoundParameters` when the parameter is omitted and the default value is applied. So I need to modify my check to explicitely check that:

```
if (-not $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Target') -or $PSBoundParameters.Target -eq 'A')) {
    # Add new parameter here...
}
```

I don’t really like this solution as it will unnecessarily tie the dynamic parameter addition with the default values. Ideally, I would want to be able to change the default value without having to touch anything else. Is there any way to access the actual parameter value from within the `DynamicParam` block? Or is there at least a possibility to access the parameter definition and access the default value?

Comment: Can't you just make `$Target` mandatory and drop the default value? It would make life so much simpler :P

Comment: @Graimer Well, I guess I *could* do that, but optional parameters with default values are so much nicer. Also, everybody can do simple :P

Comment: @poke 'but fails when the parameter is omitted' ... What's exactly fails? I'm trying your code and behave like expected.. maybe I miss something.. Have you set `Set-PSDebug -strict` ?

Comment: @C.B. Put the code into a `.ps1` and call it without specifying any parameters. It will fail with an `VariableIsUndefined` error on the `if`. (PowerShell 3 btw).

Comment: @poke Ok, at the moment I'm on a v2 and I've no error, but if I do `set-psdebug -stric` I 've the error. Try to add `set-psdebug -off` maybe in v3 is ebavle by default... but IIRC is not.

Comment: @poke I've tested on a v3.0 and I've no error... try `set-psdebug -off`... somewhere you have set it to stric!

Comment: @C.B. Oh, it’s possible that I have enabled strict mode earlier to test something else! Well, what to do now… I’ll just recycle this question to ask how to solve it *in strict mode* then ;D Thank you for pointing that out though!

Comment: @poke I've posted an answer for the recyled question ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need run correctly in case `PSDebug` is running in `strict` mode  ( `set-psdebug -strict` ), you can do something like this:

```powershell
Param(
    [Parameter()]
    [ValidateSet('A', 'B')]
    [string] $Target = 'A'
)

DynamicParam {

    # Ensure $Target is defined
    try { [void]$Target }
    catch { $Target = [string]::Empty }

    if ($Target -eq 'B') {
        write-host "si si"
    }
}
end {
    Write-Host $Target
}
```

Comment: Simple but effective I guess ^^